# How to connect Delphi to an external DB?

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, firebird2.5, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm building a Delphi application, and I want to connect it to a [Firebird Database](https://firebirdsql.org/).

The database file (**.FDB**), is on a local machine of my network (let's say 192.168.1.10) and watching a YouTube tutorial, I learned how to use the `FDConnection` that, on the parameter **Database**, asks for the file path to the database. I can't inform it because it is on another PC, so how could I connect my Delphi application to an external database?

Comment: Ask admin of this "another PC" where they put the database file to. Or ask them to add alias for this file into databases.conf. https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/qsg5/firebird-5-quickstartguide.html is more useful than video.

Comment: I'm the admin lol. How woulod be the String into the Database Parameter? The FIle Is in C:\db\my_first_db.fdb

Comment: Do you use it as an embedded DB? Otherwise have you installed and running the FB server?

Comment: Enter `inet://hostname/C:\db\my_first_db.fdb` (if you're using fbclient of Firebird 3.0 or higher) or `hostname:C:\db\my_first_db.fdb` in `Database` instead of just the filename.

Comment: Regarding the tags: I am not sure when exactly, but FireDAC was not yet shipping with Delphi 2010

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes, FB is running properly; I'm able to make SQL commands on the local machine.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using FB 2.5 and received the same error as before: [FireDAC][Phys][FB]unavaliable database.

Comment: @mjn I'm using Delphi 10.2 and Firedac components are present on my Tool palette.

Comment: @Stack_Potter I don't program Delphi myself, so I'm just guessing. It is possible you need to set another property as well. Consider asking on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the path in runtime.

I would likely use a `.ini` file as suggested in the comments.

You will then need to set the database path on your `TFDConnection` from the file on startup.